# How do I loop through a multi-column listbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I am a beginner with WPF. I fear this may sound like a silly question.

I have a listbox with two columns. Each listbox item contains a horizontal stacked panel which in turn contains textblocks.

The listbox is empty, with each listbox item being added by the end-user through a couple of textboxes placed elsewhere. The first column accepts strings, and the second column accepts only percentages.

(I have attached a relevant portion of the event sub where a user is adding new rows.)

```
Private Sub btnAddItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAddSplit.Click

'...

Dim ListBoxItemName As New TextBlock
ListBoxItemName.Text = Name.Text
ListBoxItemName.Width = 170

Dim ListBoxItemValue As New TextBlock
ListBoxItemValue.Text = SplitValue.Text
ListBoxItemValue.Width = 70

Dim ListBoxStackPanel As New StackPanel
ListBoxStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
ListBoxStackPanel.Children.Add(ListBoxItemName)
ListBoxStackPanel.Children.Add(ListBoxItemValue)

Dim NewEntry As New ListBoxItem
NewEntry.Content = ListBoxStackPanel

MyListBox.Items.Add(NewEntry)

'...

End Sub
```

I would like to be able to check every time the above event is fired that the column of percentages does not exceed 100%. I have a couple of labels below the listbox itself where I would like to show the running total and the remainder.

My questions are:

1) How can I loop through the second column of percentages to show the running total and remainder?

2) Is there something more suitable than a ListBox that could make this easier?

I would appreciate any sort of guidance towards a solution on this, regardless of whether it is in VB or C#. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code sample, it appears as if you're going through the same issues I went through when I first started with WPF.  It's difficult to let go of that codebehind mentality and to embrace databinding, but I think you should give it a try.  You will probably find that it's worth it.

Ultimately, I think your best bet would be to bind some collection of objects to the listbox and then iterate through this collection, like...

`<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StringPercentageCollection}" ... />`  And bind your columns, or your textblocks, or whatever your layout is, to the public properties of "YourStringPercentageObject".

And then "StringPercentageCollection" might be an ObservableCollection (or some other collection) of `YourStringPercentageObject` in the data context.  Then you'd be able to iterate through the observable collection normally.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will look into this approach instead. Databinding, here I come!

Answer (score 0):

I would keep track of the percentage in another field if possible.  This would separate your implementation from your user interface which is generally a good idea.